# Using jQuery Data to detect a active slide and run function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am using jQuery to make a custom navigation, but I can't work out how to detect the active slide and apply a active state to the button for that slide.

I setup a jsfiddle to better show what I'm trying to do, basically the same function as the dots/pager in the slider but on the buttons 1 2 and 3.

Im new to the .data part of jQuery :P

http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/yxErC/17/

```
<div class="number" id="" data-slider="0">
  Button 1
</div>
<div class="number" id="" data-slider="1">
  Button 2
</div>
<div class="number" id="" data-slider="2">
  Button 3
</div>

<ul class="slider">
  <li data-current="1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <p>Slider-1</p>
  </li>

  <li data-current="2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <p>Slide 2</p>
  </li>

  <li data-current="3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <p> Slide 3</p>
  </li>

</ul>



   #current {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.number:hover {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Got the buttons to control the slider :)

```
var Slider;

$(document).ready(function() {
  Slider = $('.slider').bxSlider({
    pager: true
  });
  $('.number').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = $(this).attr('data-slider');
    Slider.goToSlide(index);
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to wkrout how to use data-current="1"> to add a current class to button 1  and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxErC/23/)**.

You could add class to the clicked button and remove it from other button inside click event :

```
$('.number').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = $(this).attr('data-slider');

    $('.number').removeClass('active'); //Remove class active from all buttons
    $(this).addClass('active'); //Add active class to the clicked one

    Slider.goToSlide(index);
});
```

Because you're trying to have buttons go active relating to the slide you could use `onSlideBefore()` callback to `add/remove` active class to buttons based on `data-slider` :

```
Slider = $('.slider').bxSlider({
  pager: true,
  onSlideBefore: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
      $('.number').removeClass('active');
      $('.number[data-slider="'+newIndex+'"]').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Hoep this helps.

Comment: :-/ i thought of that but it will not go active and change when you use the slider controls like the dots will

Comment: im trying to have my buttons go active the same way the dots do

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, you want from the slider controls to add active class just like the buttons do?

Comment: ok, i am trying to have my buttons go active relating to the slide that is on screen, the same way the dots in the slider UI go darker for the current slide

Comment: on slide 1 button 1 goes active. slide to slide 2 and button 2 goes active and button 1 goes inactive and so on

Comment: :D testing @Zakaria Acharki

Comment: ($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) ah so there placeholders? @Zakaria Acharki

Comment: Not sure what is the question but take a look at http://bxslider.com/options#onSlideBefore for more informations.

Comment: Ah i see @Zakaria Acharki, hmm can't get it to work in my jsfiddle so far :( the guy below  you found a interesting way of doing it, not sure what is the best

Comment: Not sure why are you choosing a not simple method to do this @Timothy? why you want all those variable and events when you could use predefined callback of library.. IMO and if i have choice i'll not choose the other answer as correct answer because it's using a work arround solution instead of simple one.

Comment: OK @Zakaria Acharki  show me yours working because i can't get it working and i will award you the greentick :) and i think your right! :D

Comment: What you mean by show me your working i've updated my answer and fiddle 3 hours ago, and it's working http://jsfiddle.net/yxErC/23/.

Comment: Sorry! @Zakaria Acharki i missed that!!

Comment: THANKS! works great, and is far smaller and has no bugs

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make custom 'Previous / Next Page' button? If so, you can get current('active') page by calling `getCurrentSlide()`. Check documentation on http://bxslider.com/option for detail.
And if you just want to make navigation control outside of slide, there is an example on bxslider page : http://bxslider.com/examples/custom-next-prev-selectors

Comment: ah no, if you see the fiddle there is a button for each slide

Comment: then you can use onSlideBefore() / onSlideAfter() callback for detecting slide transition.(it's described in http://bxslider.com/options ) the function has oldIndex / newIndex in parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var Slider;
var minState = 0;
var maxState = 2;
var currState = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  Slider = $('.slider').bxSlider({
    pager: true
  });

  var changeActiveLink = function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.number[data-slider='+currState+']').addClass('active');
  }
  $('.number').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = $(this).attr('data-slider');
    Slider.goToSlide(index);
    currState = index;
    changeActiveLink();
  });
  $('.bx-pager-link').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var activeButton = $(this).data('slide-index');
    currState = activeButton;
    changeActiveLink();
  });
  $('.bx-next').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(currState == maxState) {
        currState = 0;
    } else {
        currState++;
    }
    changeActiveLink();
  });
  $('.bx-prev').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(currState == 0) {
        currState = maxState;
    } else {
        currState--;
    }
    changeActiveLink();
  })

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yxErC/32/

Comment: :D that works, almost except for when i use the custom nav,  i think i can fix that though L:D

Comment: Oh you tired to the slider controls :D @Brendan Quinn

Comment: Yup, all nav methods should now talk to all other nav methods

Comment: Thanks! works great :), hmm need to look at your code more im not sure how to add more slides?

Comment: Basically, add slides exactly as you were doing before, add a custom link that follows the same pattern (data-slider=3, 4, etc) and then change var maxState = 2 to whatever the final number of slides -1 is and that should do it.

Comment: Made it a bit more robust; I'd left something out with the check to loop the active slide number back around from maxSlides to 0 http://jsfiddle.net/yxErC/32/

Comment: Nice! @Brendan Quinn hmm found one bug if you slide to fast the active gets out of sync with the slide number, need a .stop or something to prevent that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105620/discussion-between-brendan-quinn-and-timothy).